# How do I identify a blank uniqueidentifier in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, uniqueidentifier, uuid

I'm getting a `uniqueidentifier` into a Stored Procedure that looks like this

`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

This seems like a simple thing, but how can identify that this is a blank `uniqueidentifier`?

If I get a value like this `DDB72E0C-FC43-4C34-A924-741445153021` I want to do X

If I get a value like this `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` I do Y

Is there a more elegant way then counting up the zeros?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 35, accepted):

compare to

```
cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)
```

?

Comment: even shorter: `CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)`, shorterer: `CAST(0x AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)`

Answer (score 4):

Just create an EmptyGuid variable and compare against that:

```
DECLARE @EmptyGuid UniqueIdentifier
SET @EmptyGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IF (@TheGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
    SELECT 'Do Y'
ELSE
    SELECT 'Do X'
```

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is to use a constant for the empty GUID

```
DECLARE @EmptyGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @EmptyGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

OR

```
DECLARE @EmptyGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @EmptyGuid = 0x0
```

and you just compare them

```
IF @parameter = @EmptyGuid
    DO Y
ELSE
    DO X
```

Note: you don't need to use casts and converts

Answer (score 1):

This also works.

```
DECLARE @EmptyGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 0x0);  
SELECT @EmptyGuid
```

Comment: The question was on SQL-Server 2005 yours will work from 2008 up.